# Run Python script for many rows in an excel

Tags: python, excel

I have a Python script that uses two files for running (they are excel files that the script takes as dataframes. Both excels are called in the same way but they are saved in different folders. It is defined in the script from which folders has to take the files and the name of the file). I have to execute this same script for more than 100 pair of files. The execution is the same for all of them.
Is there a way to make that the script considers and be executed for each pair of excels automatically? Without having to write the same lines of code for each pair of excel files

folderA contains:
fileA_1.xlsx
fileA_30.xlsx
...etc

folderB contains:
fileB_1.xlsx
fileB_30.xlsx
...etc

I have, for fileA_1 and fileB_1, the following script:

```
import pandas as pd

writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter('file1.xlsx')

fileA_1 = pd.read_excel('folderA\\fileA_1.xlsx')
fileB_1 = pd.read_excel('folderB\\fileB_1.xlsx')

file1_merge = fileA_1.merge(fileB_1, how = 'left', indicator = True)
file1_merge_count = file1_merge.shape[0]
file1_merge_count


file1_merge.to_excel(writer1, 'file1_comparison', index = False)
```

I need to replicate this same script for each pair of files I have to analize.

Comment: Would be helpful to create a [reprex]. Sounds like you need a loop, and some function(s).

Comment: Hi! I added it in the question above. Thanks!